# Use of FastLane in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

Can we submit the app(.ipa) for testing purposes or production release using Jenkins Only, or we need some other tools like Fastlane to submit the app? Why we use Fastlane with Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without Fastlane, but it is more complicate. Apple and Google exposes official APIs to do all these things. Fastlane is just a wrapper for these APIs. A more user friendly wrapper.

For the use case you are mentioning, I suggest you to check out [Pilot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/) to send the ipa to Testflight and [Deliver](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/) to send the ipa directly to the appstore.